# WSO2 Error in retrieving policy agreement

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I want to connect my android phone to the WSO2 server on Windows 10, I followed the guide:
[Quick Start](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM320/Android+Device)
After entering the server IP and its port, and the user's credentials, the "Retrieving policy agreement" message appeared and after a while the message changed to: "Enrollment failed, please contact administrator".

The iot-server.bat doesn't show any error. However, following error occurs while running analytics.bat:

```
 [2018-11-17 14:35:01,631] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:256)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeScript(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask.execute(AnalyticsTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: What's your android version? Which port you entered in the android app, 9443? Also add full error message "Enrollment Failed ...".

Comment: @MehranTorki the port will be 8280 right ? or 9443 ? As given in the [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Android+Device) on 10th step it seems to be 8280.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix error "Enrollment failed" when trying WSO2 IoT 3.3.0 android enrollment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003799/how-to-fix-error-enrollment-failed-when-trying-wso2-iot-3-3-0-android-enrollme)