# How to fix error "Enrollment failed" when trying WSO2 IoT 3.3.0 android enrollment?

Tags: java, android, wso2, wso2-iot

I set up a new server windows 2012R2 in a VM machine. The latest active-mq and Apache-ant are downloaded. Oracle JDK 8u192 is used. After installation and setup of the WSO2 IoT application, I cannot enroll an android device.

I installed the WSO2IOT by following the instructions in the online documentations for version 3.3.0.

**CARBON_HOME** and **JAVA_HOME** are set up in environment variables already.

The process of steps that I go are as follows:

1. I start the `activemq` by running it inside a cmd window as instructed by the documentation.
2. I start broker.bat in another cmd window
3. I start iot-server.bat in another cmd window
4. I start analytics.bat in another cmd window
5. Everything starts and I end up with the text "Carbon .. has stared in ** milliseconds.
6. I open my management console on https port 9443\devicemgt and login as admin no problem.
7. After that I connect my galaxy A5 2016 model with android 7.0 to the same network via WiFi. Download the app via QR code from my PC screen to the mobile phone. Install the app and try to register. The IP which I enter is static in the VM and of course I add `8280` port in the wso2 management app on the phone. Then I login with *admin/admin* credentials which logins successfully but right after that it posts an message on the phone that it is receiving policy and here it stops. The little circle spins (loading) and nothing happens for few minutes after which I get an error **"Enrollment failed. Contact the administrator. Enrollment failed."** no other message or anything.

On the analytics cmd window I got the following error inside my VM:

```
[2018-12-20 11:00:00,037] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: nulljava.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:256)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeScript(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask.execute(AnalyticsTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And that is basically it I cant move on forward from here. I tried with different java jdk versions as old as 8u144 and I tried with openJDK 8 LTSu191 to no avail.

Other things like creating policies in the devicemgt portal, creating users and browsing the portal works fine.

Did anyone encounter this issue and manage to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used WM windows10. The situation fully corresponded to that described by you, with only one difference - I also had an error on the page with the preservation of policies for Android. I also saw that the default policies for windows are reflected in the platform configuration section, and the android policies are missing and cannot be saved due to the error you described. However, in the wso2 home directory  I found the Android configuration file in which the default policy !!! was done.
 Next, I used ADB to watch the log from the Android device, at the time of binding (enrollment). He only confirmed the previously received information. I saw a 404 http error at the time the device attempted to get a policy agreement. Point.

Unexpected outcome. I downloaded version 3.1.0 instead of the current version 3.3.0. I started the batch file. I went to the platform configuration section, to the Android configuration - the default agreement policy was displayed correctly and you can change it and save the changes. The binding procedure (enrollment) passed without problems - the policy was obtained by the device and then everything went according to official instructions. I fully realize that this is not the answer to the question you raised, but at the same time it can help with a quick start. I hope.

p.s. I tried versions 3.3.1 and 3.3.0 - in both there is a similar problem with the enrollment. Version 3.1.0 does not have this problem. Versions tested on Ubuntu and WM Windows10.
Of course it would be great if the developer representatives tell you where to dig, to use a more current version. Have a nice day.

additionaly - also good work with 3.2.0

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, it solved my problem for enrollment and analytics didn't give the error in the question anymore.